# Docx to html conversion through php code in centos 7 via browser run not working

Tags: php

```
$result = shell_exec('export HOME=/var/www/html/ && soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/xyz.docx');
   echo $result;
```

docx to html conversion through php code in centos 7 via browser run not working, Please someone help me on this.....